# Java Generics to variable

Tags: java, generics

How can a java generics assign to variable and then pass it? **I don't want to do this**:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

if (someCondition) {
    myClass.<Foo>getDetails();
} else if (someCondition) {
    myClass.<Bar>getDetails();
} ... more conditional objects
```

How can I achieve this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
JavaGeneric jg;
if (someCondition) {
   jg = Foo;
} else if (someCondition) {
   jg = Bar;
}

myClass.<jg>getDetails();
```

Is this possible? I've tried to search the documentation about `java generics` but there's no example like this or how to assign it on a variable, they only have examples of passing it on the `method/class (T)`.

**Update:**

The `getDetails()` is on the `object`:

```
public class MyClass {
   <T> void getDetails() {
      //call method that uses T...
   }
}
```

Comment: You can have an interface that is implemented by Foo and Bar. Hope this serve as hint!

Comment: How? I've tried to search with my same condition but I can't find any solution.

Comment: by the way generics in java are actually called "Parameterised Types"

Comment: If you ever need to do `foo.<MyClass>someMethod();` it's very likely that you're misusing generics. Ordinarily you should be able to rely on type inference.

Comment: @Michael, I'm using it as `myClass.<Foo>someMethod()`, I'm passing it on my Retrofit API call to distinguish the generic response field.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve, what you are expecting, you need an interface and class should implement it.

```
interface JavaGeneric
{
   public String getDetails();
}
```

And, now implement it in classes.

```
class Foo implements JavaGeneric
{
     public String getDetails()
     {
           return "Foo";
     }
}
```

And,

```
class Bar implements JavaGeneric
{
     public String getDetails()
     {
           return "Bar";
     }
}
```

Now, create instance in your `if-else` and at the end call `getDetails` method

```
JavaGeneric jg;
if (someCondition) {
   jg = new Foo();
} else if (someCondition) {
   jg = new Bar();
}

jg.getDetails ();
```

**==Update==**

I'm not quite sure, what exactly you are trying to achieve. But, assuming you need to generalized the return type of `getDetails` method.

```
interface JavaGeneric<T>
{
   public T getDetails();
}
```

And, then while implementing

```
class Foo<T> implements JavaGeneric<T>
{
     public T getDetails()
     {
          // your code
     }
}
```

Comment: It seems that I've mislead the details on my question, let me update it a second

Comment: Please see my updated code, it seems that I've mislead everyone, sorry.

Comment: @TentenPonce  what do you mean by `<T> void getDetails` ?

Comment: It is a method from `MyClass`, that's what I am calling, and I'm passing on to that. That's exactly what's on my code.

Comment: @TentenPonce I don't know, what exactly you are asking, but as per my understanding, I updated my code. Let me know

Answer (score 2):

```
interface JavaGeneric {
public String getDetails(); //also you can have default methods implementation here.
}

class Foo implements JavaGeneric {
 public String getDetails(){
   return "Foo Details";
 }
}


class Bar implements JavaGeneric {
 public String getDetails(){
   return "Bar Details";
 }
}


// Somewhere in code

JavaGeneric jg;
if (someCondition) { //lets say this is false
   jg = Foo;
} else if (someCondition) { // lets say this is true
   jg = Bar;
}

jg.getDetails(); //we will get "Bar Details"
```

Comment: Please see my updated code, it seems that I've mislead everyone, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Just call

```
myClass.getDetails()
```

Due to type erasure there is no difference between

```
myClass.<T>getDetails()
```

And

```
myClass.<R>getDetails()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are declaring `getDetails()` as generic only because you want to use the type variable `T` in the method body. The type variable `T` is not part of the method's signature or of its return type.

This is usually not needed. Depending on what your method actually does, maybe you can remove the `<T>` from the method declaration and replace `T` with `?` everywhere in the message body.

Comment: I'm passing the `T` on my API call from Retrofit to distinguish the object to be used on a generic response

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a type from a variable to a method, use a `Class<?>` parameter:

```
public class MyClass {
   void getDetails(Class<?> cls) {
      //...
   }
}
```

Then you just need an object of type `Class<?>`:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
Class<?> jg;
if (someCondition) {
   jg = Foo.class;
} else if (someCondition) {
   jg = Bar.class;
}

myClass.getDetails(jg);
```

Generics only exist at compile time due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so it's impossible to pass a generic type parameter from a run-time variable. It's not clear what you're actually doing with the type in `getDetails`, but if you can't make it work with a `Class<?>` object, you'll need to stick with the code in your first example and have a separate method call for each explicit type.